# My sister hack my computer

Tags: email, security, privacy

my computer was hack by my sister.
She all but told me with her constant comment about thing she could only know by have access to my computer or internet traffic(I tryed to confront her but she just smiled and said "there isnt any privacy on a computer"). She doesnt have physical access to my computer but we do email each other often and my email was hacked months ago. I eventually got access back.I dont to much care for having the most secure computer in the world, I just want privacy from people I know. I've tryed factory restoring my computer anti viruse and malware but the comments kept coming.Now im try a VPN.

So I think if she doesnt know where to look(my dns, ip, gateway, dhcp server etc) then the problem is solved.
My question is "What do I need to change on my network to avoid her?Also do i need a new computer, modem, router, or, and ISP?

Comment: You need to become "serious" about securing your computer, your lack of being serious allowed this to happen (if it even bappened), have you identified his she gained access to your computer remotely?

Answer (score 1):

A similar situation happened to a relative.

1. [Scan for viruses, malware, etc](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2388652,00.asp).  It's possible your sister has installed a Keylogger at some point.  If this is the case, anything else you try will be useless.
2. Change your email password to a [strong password](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/tips-for-creating-a-strong-password).  For added security, use a different computer to do so, say one at a library, school or work.
3. Set up [two factor authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-factor_authentication).  Most popular email systems support some form of this.  You will need to look up the relevant method for your provider.
4. Do not reuse your passwords: use a different password for every site you log into.  A [Password Manager](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2407168,00.asp) can help you with that.  Most password managers will also include tools to check the security of your passwords, and will flag weak or reused passwords, and usually also those included in cracked website leaks.